# How to select last entry on a given date

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get a count of active users in a table that doesn't delete or update records, instead, it adds to the table and assumes the last entry is the most valid. However, for historical counts I need a count of actives for each day.

Having the following data:

```
--------------------------------------
id | user_id | type |   date
--------------------------------------
 1   sam       New      2017-10-10
 2   john      New      2017-10-12
 3   sam       Change   2017-10-14
 4   sam       Cancel   2017-10-15
```

I need to be able to count, how many "Active" users I had by date.  What I am expecting to get is something such as:

```
---------------------
 Date      | Active
---------------------
...
2017-10-08   0     <-- Prior there were none
2017-10-09   0
2017-10-10   1
2017-10-11   1     <-- Fill-in dates
2017-10-12   2     <-- Cumulative adding
2017-10-13   2
2017-10-14   2     <-- A change is irrelevant 
2017-10-15   1     <-- A Cancel should decrease the count
```

I do have a calendar_table and tried various suggestions but can't seem to get it right.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Give us a starting point.  Show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT date, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS active FROM data GROUP BY date;
```

Is that what you want to achieve? Sounds pretty simple, but maybe I misunderstood your question...

**UPDATE**

Also I suppose you need a separate table "dates" containing all dates. Like this:

```
---------------------
Date      
---------------------
...
2017-10-08   
2017-10-09   
2017-10-10   
2017-10-11    
2017-10-12   
2017-10-13   
2017-10-14   
2017-10-15
```

Then you need perform a LEFT/RIGHT JOIN to the result which you get with the SQL query at the top of my answer.

```
SELECT dates.date, COALESCE(result.active, 0)
FROM dates
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT date, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS active
    FROM data
    GROUP BY date
) AS result ON dates.date = result.date
```

And the result might look like this:

```
---------------------
 Date      | Active
---------------------
...
2017-10-08   0 
2017-10-09   0
2017-10-10   1
2017-10-11   1 
2017-10-12   2 
2017-10-13   2
2017-10-14   2  
2017-10-15   1
```

`COALESCE` replaces `null`'s with `0`

I am answering with my phone, so I have not checked the validity of my queries. But you got my idea

Comment: You did not consider the fact that a single user may have more than 1 entry, so you need to do a max() or something

Comment: It will not have. It is grouped by date

Comment: Anyway, I have not checked it yet

Comment: @smorhaim I have understood you statement. Just added `DISTINCT` inside `COUNT` (see updated query)

Comment: Is the subquery necessary? Wouldn't be `SELECT dates.date,
       COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT user_id), 0) AS active
FROM dates
LEFT JOIN data ON data.date = dates.date
GROUP BY dates.date` enough?

Comment: @JanZeiseweis, you are right. It was just easier for me to write subquery. So many men, so many minds. :)